# How to make an API call in Angular using a get function?

Tags: angular, http, get

I need to call the following API,
https://lhp-command-center-webapi-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/sites/List, using a get function without passing any arguments.  How do I do this inside my Angular application, what is the snippet of code I need to use and I do need import any specific libraries or pass any specific variables in the constructor?

The APIS need to show up on the screen below.

[image: Site Page]

I should receive the following 5 sites,

> {"results": [ {"id": "5c655c35-0e6f-47a2-a2c7-26714a135598","auditable": {"createdBy": "testuser@lhpes.com","createdServerDateUTC": "2023-02-23T17:30:56.363655Z","createdLocalTime": "2023-02-23T17:30:56Z","lastUpdateBy": null,"lastUpdateServerDateUTC": null,"lastUpdateLocalTime": null,"deletedBy": null,"deletedLocalTime": null,"deletedServerDateUTC": null},
> "name": "Site Name 6","address": "Address 6","description": "Description 6","contactInfo": "Contact Info 6","companyId": "4a71925e-0345-49db-9e76-a067c03d1483"},
>  {"id": "4b47d284-3d41-4537-93ab-b3b26a5ef710","auditable": {"createdBy": "feliceferri@lhpes.com","createdServerDateUTC": "2023-02-21T16:42:05.9256249Z","createdLocalTime": "2023-02-21T16:38:37.081Z","lastUpdateBy": null,"lastUpdateServerDateUTC": null,"lastUpdateLocalTime": null,"deletedBy": null,"deletedLocalTime": null,"deletedServerDateUTC": null},
> "name": "SiteName2","address": "asdf","description": "asdf","contactInfo": null,"companyId": "4a71925e-0345-49db-9e76-a067c03d1483"},
>  {"id": "1fd348a4-791d-4f43-bbd6-41637ed73f4b","auditable": {"createdBy": "feliceferri@lhpes.com","createdServerDateUTC": "2023-02-21T16:46:20.9211014Z","createdLocalTime": "2023-02-21T16:38:37.081Z","lastUpdateBy": null,"lastUpdateServerDateUTC": null,"lastUpdateLocalTime": null,"deletedBy": null,"deletedLocalTime": null,"deletedServerDateUTC": null},
> "name": "SiteName3","address": "asdf3","description": "asdf3","contactInfo": null,"companyId": "4a71925e-0345-49db-9e76-a067c03d1483"}, 
> {"id": "522b5f3e-32e5-4586-8008-c9e49b22e425","auditable": {"createdBy": "feliceferri@lhpes.com","createdServerDateUTC": "2023-02-21T16:47:23.598851Z","createdLocalTime": "2023-02-21T16:38:37.081Z","lastUpdateBy": null,"lastUpdateServerDateUTC": null,"lastUpdateLocalTime": null,"deletedBy": null,"deletedLocalTime": null,"deletedServerDateUTC": null}, "name": "SiteName4","address": "asdf4","description": "asdf4","contactInfo": null,"companyId": "4a71925e-0345-49db-9e76-a067c03d1483"},  {"id": "ec6b076d-11d8-40ee-a43f-d3e82060211a","auditable": {"createdBy": "feliceferri@lhpes.com","createdServerDateUTC": "2023-02-21T16:48:03.4976548Z","createdLocalTime": "2023-02-21T16:38:37.081Z","lastUpdateBy": null,"lastUpdateServerDateUTC": null,"lastUpdateLocalTime": null,"deletedBy": null,"deletedLocalTime": null,"deletedServerDateUTC": null}, "name": "SiteName5","address": "asdf5","description": "asdf5","contactInfo": null,"companyId": "4a71925e-0345-49db-9e76-a067c03d1483"} ], "totalNumberOfRecords": 5}

Comment: Can you please mention the error as well?

Comment: Without seeing the error you got, we would only throw assumption answers out there.

Answer (score 1):

If you use rxjs with a version above 6.6.7 and the old way of consuming observables is deprecated, try this new way of consuming it.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

totalAngularPackages: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.http.get<any>('https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=scope:angular').subscribe({
    next: (data) => {
        this.totalAngularPackages = data.total;
    },
    error: (error) => {
        console.log(error)
    },
    complete: () => {
        console.log('complete')
    }
  })      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In angular the best practice when calling APIs is to create a service that you can inject anywhere in your application which prevents a lot of redundancies and issues.

There are a lot of ways you could approach this, [@Claudio Gutiérrez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20940969/claudio-guti%C3%A9rrez) method works and will give you the desired output in the short term, but it is unadvisable to follow that approach. As it is not using any service which can cause redundancy and can be error prone. Also, using the type `<any>` undermines the use of typescript.

My advice is if you want to build good habits you need to first convert the json output you receive from the API to an interface.

- To create an interface: `ng g interface interfaceName`
- You can use this [website](http://json2ts.com/) to easily convert your json to interface

After creating your interfaces you need to now create a service where you will inject it in your components whenever you want to call the API.

- To create a service: `ng g s serviceName`

Inside your service:

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

 getList(): Observable<interfaceName>{
    return this.http.get<interfaceName>('https://lhp-command-center-webapi-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/sites/List');
 }
```

Then inside your component you can inject the service their and use it:

```
siteLists: interfaceName;

constructor(private serviceName: ServiceName) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.serviceName.getList().subscribe({
    next: (data) => {
        this.siteLists = data;
    },
    error: (error) => {
        console.log(error)
    },
    complete: () => {
        console.log('complete')
    }
  })      
}
```

You can check the below documentations for your reference:

- https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services
- https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt4

Answer (score 0):

To use http.get you need a constructor (HttpClient) and import (@angular/common/http). Your "this" need to be created too  for example

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

totalAngularPackages: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get<any>('https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=scope:angular').subscribe(data => {
        this.totalAngularPackages = data.total;
    })        
}
```